# Making a process run in the background by using fork

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I am trying to make a simple shell. When I execute a command in the child and wait for it, the code works fine. However, when I want to execute it in the background, the program just hangs there, and the prompt symbol did not show up. What else code should I add to make my child process do its work, while the parent continues on receiving another user command?

```
int
lsh_launch(char **args)
{

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("lsh");
    }
    else {
        // parent process
        if (!background) {
            wait(NULL);                 // works fine
        }
        else {
            printf("[PID]: %d\n", pid);
            // after printing the pid, the prompt symbol does not show again
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

My caller function:
After lsh_execute, the code will go back to main, and go back
to the top of the while loop, and print another command prompt.

```
int lsh_execute(char **args)
{
  int i;
  if (args[0] == NULL) { 
    // An empty command was entered, return
    return 1;
  }

  //if the command is in my predefined function list, execute
  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }
  //if not, go to launch and fork a child and execute
  return lsh_launch(args);
}
```

Code Link:
[myshell](https://github.com/Rob12312368/shell/blob/main/my_shell.c) The problem is when I type "ls &", the program do output a list of file names in the current directory, but it hangs there.

Comment: Where is the prompt shown?

Comment: We need to see the code of the _caller_ to this function. AFAICT, the code _will_ do what you want, but it's what the caller does that is [probably] incorrect. Please _edit_ your _question_ and post more code in a separate code block.

Comment: `exit(0)` after an `execvp` failure is unusual.  If `execvp` fails, I would expect a non-zero exit.  (zero exit indicates success)

Comment: @tadman it is not shown when I try to run process in the background

Comment: @CraigEstey I have updated the code. Could you please answer my question now?

Comment: Okay, you posted the immediate caller. But, that doesn't show the outermost loop and the code that prints the prompt and waits for command input [and reaps the child if `background` is set]. Instead of going back and forth, if you could post your _entire_ code as a _single_ block that can be downloaded, compiled, and run. I [or somebody else] could run it on my/their system with `gdb`.

Comment: @CraigEstey I have posted the link. Thanks for helping me so much.

Comment: That link contains the line `if(c == EOF  c == 'n')`.  That doesn't seem at all correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues:

1. After the `printf` for the prompt, we have to `fflush(stdout)` to force out the text because there is *no* newline.
2. *No* reaping of background children, so they become zombies.
3. This would interfere with `wait(NULL)` for the *next* foreground command. (e.g.) `sleep 5 & ; pwd` would mess up the wait for 2nd command.
4. To fix: the program should periodically call `waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG)` to reap the zombie background children.
5. Also, with background jobs, a previous one might complete *before* the next foreground job. So, we want to foreground to change from `wait` to `waitpid`
6. Doing `signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN)` prevents `wait*` from seeing/reaping a background pid.
7. This would interfere with subsequent `wait(NULL)` for foreground commands.
8. The code for the `replay` command that attaches to the linked list was wrong. The compiler flagged this when compiled with warnings (e.g. `-Wall`).
9. Compiler warnings about "unused" or "set but not used" variables.
10. We should `fflush` both `stdout` and `stderr` prior to a `fork`.

Some improvements:

1. Added "job control" for background jobs and `jobs` and `wait` commands.
2. Added debug printing with `dbgprt`.

---

In the code below, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"

char *currentdir;
int tokencount;
typedef struct node {
    char str[64];
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *top = NULL;
node *cur = NULL;

#if 1
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        int sverr = errno; \
        printf(_fmt); \
        errno = sverr; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: implement job control
#if 1
struct jobctl {
    int job_jobno;                      // job number
    pid_t job_pid;                      // child pid
    int job_status;                     // child status
    struct jobctl *job_next;            // list link
};
struct jobctl *joblist;                 // list of background jobs
int jobcount;                           // highest job number

// jobreap -- reap all detached/background jobs (children)
void
jobreap(void)
{

    // wait for all background jobs
    while (joblist != NULL) {
        int status;

        // reap any child (non-blocking)
        pid_t pid = waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG);

        // more children are pending [but not yet finished]
        if (pid == 0)
            break;

        dbgprt("jobreap: WAITPID pid=%d status=%8.8X\n",pid,status);

        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("jobreap: error -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        // find it in our list of detached/background jobs
        struct jobctl *cur;
        struct jobctl *prev = NULL;
        for (cur = joblist;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->job_next) {
            if (cur->job_pid == pid)
                break;
            prev = cur;
        }

        // reaping child of one of our children (i.e. grandchild) that is _not_
        // in our list
        if (cur == NULL) {
            printf("[grandchild]: pid %d, status %8.8X\n", pid, status);
            continue;
        }

        printf("[background]: pid %d, %8.8X, job %d\n",
            pid, status, cur->job_jobno);

        // we don't do anything with this but ...
        cur->job_status = status;

        // remove our child from list
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->job_next = cur->job_next;
        else
            joblist = cur->job_next;

        // release storage
        free(cur);

        // reset job count if we've reaped _all_ of our direct children
        if (joblist == NULL)
            jobcount = 0;
    }
}

int
lsh_jobs(char **args)
{

    for (struct jobctl *cur = joblist;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->job_next)
        printf("[%d] pid %d\n",cur->job_jobno,cur->job_pid);

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_wait(char **args)
{

    while (1) {
        jobreap();
        if (joblist == NULL)
            break;
    }

#if 0
    for (struct jobctl *cur = joblist;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->job_next)
        printf("[%d] pid %d\n",cur->job_jobno,cur->job_pid);
#endif

    return 1;
}

#endif

char *
read_line(void)
{
    int bufsize = BUFSIZ;
    int position = 0;
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
    int c;

    if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
            buffer[position] = '\0';
            return buffer;
        }
        else {
            buffer[position] = c;
        }
        position++;

        if (position >= bufsize) {
            bufsize += BUFSIZ;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
            if (!buffer) {
                fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

}

char **
split_line(char *line)
{
    int bufsize = BUFSIZ;
    int position = 0;
    char **tokens = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * bufsize);
    char *token;

    if (!tokens) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    token = strtok(line, TOK_DELIM);
    while (token != NULL) {
        tokens[position] = token;
        position++;

        if (position >= bufsize) {
            bufsize += TOK_BUFSIZE;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char *));
            if (!tokens) {
                fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
    }
    tokens[position] = NULL;
    tokencount = position;
    return tokens;

}

void
catHeadTail(char *filename, int headtail, char *line)
{

    char *ptr;
    long num;

    num = strtol(line, &ptr, 10);
    num *= -1;
    char cwd[256];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    else {
        strcat(cwd, "/");
        strcat(cwd, filename);
    }

    char lines[1000][256];
    int linecount = 0;
    FILE *input = fopen(cwd, "r");

    if (!input) {
        perror("lsh: file open error");
    }

    while (fgets(lines[linecount], 256, input) != NULL) {
        linecount++;
    }
    fclose(input);

    if (headtail == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%s", lines[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = linecount - num; i <= linecount; i++) {
            printf("%s", lines[i]);
        }
    }

}

int
lsh_launch(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
// NOTE/BUG: unused
#if 0
    pid_t wpid;
    int state;
#endif
    int background = 0;

    if (!strcmp(args[tokencount - 1], "&")) {
        background = 1;
        args[tokencount - 1] = '\0';
    }

    dbgprt("lsh_launch: PARENT pid=%d pgrp=%d\n",getpid(),getpgrp());

#if 1
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
#endif
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        dbgprt("lsh_launch: BEF pgid=%d\n",getpgrp());
        setpgid(0, 0);
        dbgprt("lsh_launch: AFT pgid=%d\n",getpgrp());

        if (tokencount >= 4 && !strcmp(args[2], "|"))   // pipleline
        {
            if (!strcmp(args[0], "cat") && !strcmp(args[2], "|")) {
                if (!strcmp(args[3], "head"))
                    catHeadTail(args[1], 1, args[4]);   // head
                else
                    catHeadTail(args[1], 0, args[4]);   // tail
            }
        }
        else if (tokencount >= 3 && !strcmp(args[1], "<")) {
            char *temp[3];

            temp[0] = args[0];
            temp[1] = args[2];
            temp[2] = NULL;
            if (execvp(temp[0], temp) == -1) {
                perror("lsh");
            }
        }
        else if (tokencount >= 4 && !strcmp(args[2], ">")) {
            char lines[1000][256];
            int linecount = 0;
            FILE *input = fopen(args[1], "r");
            FILE *output = fopen(args[3], "w");

            if (!input || !output) {
                perror("lsh: file open error");
            }

            while (fgets(lines[linecount], 256, input) != NULL) {
                linecount++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
                fputs(lines[i], output);
            }
        }
        else if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("lsh");
    }
    else {
        // parent process
        if (! background) {
            dbgprt("lsh_launch: WAIT/BEF pid=%d\n",pid);
            int status;
// NOTE/BUG: with detached jobs, a detached job might complete _before_ this
// one -- so wait for pid specifically
#if 0
            pid = wait(&status);
#else
            pid = waitpid(pid,&status,0);
#endif
            dbgprt("lsh_launch: WAIT/AFT pid=%d status=%8.8X\n",pid,status);
        }
        else {
// NOTE/BUG: doing this prevents wait from working correctly on the child
#if 0
            signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
#endif
// NOTE/FIX: implement "job control" for background job
#if 1
            // get new job control
            struct jobctl *job = calloc(1,sizeof(*job));

            job->job_pid = pid;
            job->job_jobno = ++jobcount;

            printf("[PID]: %d job %d\n", pid, job->job_jobno);

            // add it to list
            job->job_next = joblist;
            joblist = job;
#endif
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int lsh_cd(char **args);
int lsh_help(char **args);
int lsh_exit(char **args);
int lsh_echo(char **args);
int lsh_record(char **args);
int lsh_replay(char **args);
int lsh_mypid(char **args);

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
char *builtin_str[] = {
    "cd",
    "help",
    "exit",
    "echo",
    "record",
    "replay",
    "mypid",
#if 1
    "jobs",
    "wait",
#endif
};

/* all the buildin func*/
int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
    lsh_cd,
    lsh_help, lsh_exit, lsh_echo, lsh_record, lsh_replay, lsh_mypid,
#if 1
    lsh_jobs,
    lsh_wait,
#endif
};

int
lsh_num_builtins()
{
    return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}

int
lsh_cd(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
    }
    else {
        if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_help(char **args)
{
    int i;

    printf("Stephen Brennan's LSH\n");
    printf("Type program names and arguments, and hit enter.\n");
    printf("The following are built in:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
        printf("  %s\n", builtin_str[i]);
    }

    printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_exit(char **args)
{
    return 0;
}

int
lsh_echo(char **args)
{
    if (!strcmp(args[1], "-n")) {
        for (int i = 2; i < tokencount; i++) {
            printf("%s ", args[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i < tokencount; i++) {
            printf("%s ", args[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_record(char **args)
{
    int i = 1;
    node *go = top;

    while (go != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, go->str);
        go = go->next;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_replay(char **args)
{
    node *go;

    go = top;

    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(args[1]) - 1; i++) {
        go = go->next;
    }
    node *add = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    add->next = NULL;
    strcpy(add->str, go->str);
    cur->next = add;
    cur = cur->next;

    char **command = split_line(go->str);

    pid_t wpid;
    int state;

#if 1
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
#endif
    pid_t pd = fork();

    if (pd == 0) {
        if (execvp(command[0], command) == -1) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pd < 0) {
        perror("lsh");
    }
    else {
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pd, &state, WUNTRACED);
            dbgprt("lsh_replay: pd=%d wpid=%d state=%8.8X\n",
                pd,wpid,state);
// NOTE/FIX: wpid is set but not used -- this is a dummy test
#if 1
            if (wpid != pd)
                continue;
#endif
        } while (!WIFEXITED(state) && !WIFSIGNALED(state));
    }

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_mypid(char **args)
{
    int pid = getpid();

    if (!strcmp(args[1], "-i")) {
        printf("%d", pid);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(args[1], "-p")) {
#if 0
        int c;
#endif
        FILE *file;
        char path[30] = "/proc/";
        char content[512];
        char *token;

        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/stat");
        file = fopen(path, "r");
        if (file) {
            int i = 1;

            fgets(content, 512, file);
            token = strtok(content, TOK_DELIM);
            while (i < 4) {
                token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
                i++;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else {
            printf("not existed");
        }

        printf("%d", atoi(token));
    }
    else if (!strcmp(args[1], "-c")) {
#if 0
        int c;
#endif
        FILE *file;
        char path[30] = "/proc/";
#if 0
        char pids[10];
#endif
        char content[512];
        char *token;

        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/task/");
        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/children");
        file = fopen(path, "r");
        if (file) {
            fgets(content, 512, file);
            token = strtok(content, TOK_DELIM);
            printf("%s", token);
            while (token != NULL) {
                token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
                printf("%s", token);
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "can not open the file\n");
        }
        return 1;

    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_execute(char **args)
{
    int i;

    if (args[0] == NULL) {
        // An empty command was entered.
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
        if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
            return (*builtin_func[i]) (args);
        }
    }

    return lsh_launch(args);
}

void
shell_loop()
{
    int counter = 0;
    char *line;
    char **args;
    char *allline = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
    int state = 1;

    while (state == 1) {
#if 1
        jobreap();
#endif

        printf(">>>$ ");
// NOTE/FIX: must flush the output because the printf does _not_ end in newline
#if 1
        fflush(stdout);
#endif
        line = read_line();
#if 1
        jobreap();
#endif
        strcpy(allline, line);
        args = split_line(line);
        if (args[0] == NULL) {          // space or \t
            continue;
        }
        else if (strcmp(args[0], "replay")) // not replay
        {
            if (counter == 0) {
                top = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
                strcpy(top->str, allline);
                top->next = NULL;

                cur = top;
            }
            else {
                node *m = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

                strcpy(m->str, allline);
                m->next = NULL;

                cur->next = m;
                cur = m;
            }
            if (counter >= 16) {
                node *del;

                del = top;
                top = top->next;
                free(del);
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(args[0], "replay"))    // replay
        {
            node *go = top;

            for (int i = 0; i < atoi(args[1]) - 1; i++) {
                go = go->next;
            }
            node *add = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

            strcpy(add->str, go->str);
            add->next = NULL;
            cur->next = add;

            if (counter >= 16) {
                node *del = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
// NOTE/BUG: this is flagged by the compiler (i.e.) it sees that the value
// is discarded
#if 0
                del = top;
                top = top->next;
#else
                del->next = top;
                top = del;
#endif
                // free(del);
            }
        }
        state = lsh_execute(args);

        free(line);
        free(args);
        // free(allline); don't really know why it can not be freed
        counter++;

    }
}

int
main()
{

    shell_loop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

*Note:* Redacted for SO space limits ...

> 1. Why is fflush necessary with "\n"?

Your *prompt* does *not*: `printf(">>>$ ");`

> 2.-7. Could you please guide me to some link?

1. Download source code for `bash` and/or other shells.
2. Similar SO questions and some do background processes.
3. Years ago, I looked at how `bash` did this. I modeled changes to job control [loosely] on that.

> 10. Is that because the remaining string in the buffer that has not been printed will be copy to the child?

Default for `stdout` for TTY is *line* buffered.
For a file, it's full buffering (e.g. 4096 chars).

Then *not* doing `fflush` before a `fork` can cause *both* parent and child to flush stale data in parent's buffer.

I've updated the code:

1. Did `unifdef -k` and removed comments
2. Changed foreground to use job control vs. explicit `waitpid`
3. Fixed record/replay.
4. `shell_loop` was *not* freeing `args`
5. Changed builtins to use a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"

#define FREE(_ptr) \
    do { \
        dbgprt("FREE: " #_ptr "=%p (line %d)\n",_ptr,__LINE__); \
        free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

char *currentdir;
int tokencount;

typedef struct node {
    char *str;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// replay list
node *top = NULL;
node *cur = NULL;
int counter;

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        int sverr = errno; \
        printf(_fmt); \
        errno = sverr; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#define ALLOCP(_ptr)            malloc(sizeof(*(_ptr)))

struct builtin {
    const char *cmd_str;
    const char *cmd_help;
    int (*cmd_func)(char **);
};

#define CMDX(_cmd,_fnc,_help) \
    { .cmd_str = #_cmd, .cmd_func = _fnc, .cmd_help = _help}
#define CMD(_cmd,_help) \
    CMDX(_cmd,lsh_ ## _cmd,_help)

// job control
struct jobctl {
    int job_jobno;                      // job number
    pid_t job_pid;                      // child pid
    int job_status;                     // child status
    struct jobctl *job_next;            // list link
};
struct jobctl *joblist;                 // list of background jobs
int jobcount;                           // highest job number
pid_t fgpid;                            // foreground job

// jobreap -- reap all detached/background jobs (children)
void
jobreap(void)
{

    // wait for all background jobs
    while (joblist != NULL) {
        int status;

        // should we wait for foreground command?
        int nowait = (fgpid == 0) ? WNOHANG : 0;

        // reap any child
        pid_t pid = waitpid(-1,&status,nowait);

        // more children are pending [but not yet finished]
        // NOTE: should _not_ occur with wait for foreground
        if (pid == 0) {
            if (! nowait)
                continue;
            break;
        }

        dbgprt("jobreap: WAITPID pid=%d status=%8.8X\n",pid,status);

        // NOTE: this probably should not occur
        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("jobreap: error -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
            if (! nowait)
                continue;
            break;
        }

        // are we reaping the foreground job?
        int fgflg = (pid == fgpid);

        // find it in our list of detached/background jobs
        struct jobctl *cur;
        struct jobctl *prev = NULL;
        for (cur = joblist;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->job_next) {
            if (cur->job_pid == pid)
                break;
            prev = cur;
        }

        // reaping child of one of our children (i.e. grandchild) that is _not_
        // in our list
        if (cur == NULL) {
            if (nowait)
                printf("[grandchild]: pid %d, status %8.8X\n", pid, status);
            continue;
        }

        if (! fgflg)
            printf("[background]: pid %d, %8.8X, job %d\n",
                pid, status, cur->job_jobno);

        // we don't do anything with this but ...
        cur->job_status = status;

        // remove our child from list
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->job_next = cur->job_next;
        else
            joblist = cur->job_next;

        // release storage
        free(cur);

        // reset job count if we've reaped _all_ of our direct children
        if (joblist == NULL)
            jobcount = 0;

        // if we just reaped the foreground job, we no longer need to hard wait
        // for it
        if (fgflg)
            fgpid = 0;
    }
}

// jobadd -- get new job control
void
jobadd(pid_t pid,int fgflg)
{
    struct jobctl *job = calloc(1,sizeof(*job));

    job->job_pid = pid;
    job->job_jobno = ++jobcount;

    if (! fgflg)
        printf("[PID]: %d job %d\n", pid, job->job_jobno);

    // add it to list
    job->job_next = joblist;
    joblist = job;

    // tell jobreap to wait for this
    if (fgflg)
        fgpid = pid;
}

int
lsh_jobs(char **args)
{

    for (struct jobctl *cur = joblist;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->job_next)
        printf("[%d] pid %d\n",cur->job_jobno,cur->job_pid);

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_wait(char **args)
{

    while (1) {
        jobreap();
        if (joblist == NULL)
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}

char *
read_line(void)
{
    int bufsize = 0;
    int position = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int c;

    while (1) {
        c = getchar();

        if (position >= bufsize) {
            bufsize += 100;

            buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize + 1);

            if (!buffer) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read_line: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;

        buffer[position] = c;
        position++;
    }

    buffer[position] = '\0';
    buffer = realloc(buffer, position + 1);

    return buffer;
}

char **
split_line(char *line)
{
    int bufsize = 0;
    char **tokens = NULL;
    int position = 0;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(line, TOK_DELIM);

    while (token != NULL) {
        if (position >= bufsize) {
            bufsize += 64;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, (bufsize + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            if (!tokens) {
                fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        tokens[position] = token;
        position++;

        token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
    }

    tokens[position] = NULL;

    // trim to actual size used
    tokens = realloc(tokens, (position + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    tokencount = position;

    return tokens;

}

void
catHeadTail(char *filename, int headtail, char *line)
{
    char *ptr;
    long num;

    num = strtol(line, &ptr, 10);
    num *= -1;
    char cwd[256];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    else {
        strcat(cwd, "/");
        strcat(cwd, filename);
    }

    char lines[1000][256];
    int linecount = 0;
    FILE *input = fopen(cwd, "r");

    if (!input) {
        perror("lsh: file open error");
    }

    while (fgets(lines[linecount], 256, input) != NULL) {
        linecount++;
    }
    fclose(input);

    if (headtail == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%s", lines[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = linecount - num; i <= linecount; i++) {
            printf("%s", lines[i]);
        }
    }
}

int
lsh_launch(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int background = 0;

    if (!strcmp(args[tokencount - 1], "&")) {
        background = 1;
        args[tokencount - 1] = '\0';
    }

    dbgprt("lsh_launch: PARENT pid=%d pgrp=%d\n",getpid(),getpgrp());

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        setpgid(0, 0);

        if (tokencount >= 4 && !strcmp(args[2], "|"))   // pipleline
        {
            if (!strcmp(args[0], "cat") && !strcmp(args[2], "|")) {
                if (!strcmp(args[3], "head"))
                    catHeadTail(args[1], 1, args[4]);   // head
                else
                    catHeadTail(args[1], 0, args[4]);   // tail
            }
        }
        else if (tokencount >= 3 && !strcmp(args[1], "<")) {
            char *temp[3];

            temp[0] = args[0];
            temp[1] = args[2];
            temp[2] = NULL;
            if (execvp(temp[0], temp) == -1) {
                perror("lsh");
            }
        }
        else if (tokencount >= 4 && !strcmp(args[2], ">")) {
            char lines[1000][256];
            int linecount = 0;
            FILE *input = fopen(args[1], "r");
            FILE *output = fopen(args[3], "w");

            if (!input || !output) {
                perror("lsh: file open error");
            }

            while (fgets(lines[linecount], 256, input) != NULL) {
                linecount++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
                fputs(lines[i], output);
            }
        }
        else if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("lsh");
    }
    else {
        // parent process
        jobadd(pid,! background);
    }

    return 1;
}

int lsh_help(char **args);

int
lsh_cd(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
    }
    else {
        if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_exit(char **args)
{
    return 0;
}

int
lsh_echo(char **args)
{
    if (!strcmp(args[1], "-n")) {
        for (int i = 2; i < tokencount; i++) {
            printf("%s ", args[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i < tokencount; i++) {
            printf("%s ", args[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int
lsh_record(char **args)
{
    int i = 1;
    node *go = top;

    while (go != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, go->str);
        go = go->next;
        i++;
    }

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_replay(char **args)
{
    node *go;

    go = top;

    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(args[1]) - 1; i++) {
        go = go->next;
    }
    node *add = ALLOCP(add);

    add->next = NULL;
    strcpy(add->str, go->str);
    cur->next = add;
    cur = cur->next;

    char **command = split_line(go->str);

    pid_t wpid;
    int state;

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    pid_t pd = fork();

    if (pd == 0) {
        if (execvp(command[0], command) == -1) {
            perror("lsh");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pd < 0) {
        perror("lsh");
    }
    else {
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pd, &state, WUNTRACED);
            dbgprt("lsh_replay: pd=%d wpid=%d state=%8.8X\n",
                pd,wpid,state);
            if (wpid != pd)
                continue;
        } while (!WIFEXITED(state) && !WIFSIGNALED(state));
    }

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_mypid(char **args)
{
    int pid = getpid();

    if (!strcmp(args[1], "-i")) {
        printf("%d", pid);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(args[1], "-p")) {
        FILE *file;
        char path[30] = "/proc/";
        char content[512];
        char *token;

        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/stat");
        file = fopen(path, "r");
        if (file) {
            int i = 1;

            fgets(content, 512, file);
            token = strtok(content, TOK_DELIM);
            while (i < 4) {
                token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
                i++;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else {
            printf("not existed");
        }

        printf("%d", atoi(token));
    }
    else if (!strcmp(args[1], "-c")) {
        FILE *file;
        char path[30] = "/proc/";
        char content[512];
        char *token;

        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/task/");
        strcat(path, args[2]);
        strcat(path, "/children");
        file = fopen(path, "r");
        if (file) {
            fgets(content, 512, file);
            token = strtok(content, TOK_DELIM);
            printf("%s", token);
            while (token != NULL) {
                token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
                printf("%s", token);
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "can not open the file\n");
        }
        return 1;

    }
    return 1;
}

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
struct builtin builtin_list[] = {
    CMD(cd,"change current directory"),
    CMD(help,"internal command help"),
    CMD(exit,"exit shell"),
    CMD(echo,"echo arguments"),
    CMD(record,"show command history"),
    CMDX(replay,NULL,"replay Nth command in history"),
    CMD(mypid,"print shell pid"),
    CMD(jobs,"list background jobs"),
    CMD(wait,"wait for background jobs"),
};

#define FORALLCMD \
    struct builtin *cmd = builtin_list; \
    cmd < &builtin_list[sizeof(builtin_list) / sizeof(builtin_list[0])]; \
    ++cmd

int
lsh_help(char **args)
{

    printf("Stephen Brennan's LSH\n");
    printf("Type program names and arguments, and hit enter.\n");
    printf("The following are built in:\n");

    for (FORALLCMD)
        printf("  %s -- %s\n", cmd->cmd_str, cmd->cmd_help);

    printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");

    return 1;
}

int
lsh_execute(char **args)
{
    int builtin = 0;
    int ret = 1;

    // empty command ...
    if (args[0] == NULL)
        return ret;

    for (FORALLCMD) {
        if (strcmp(args[0], cmd->cmd_str) == 0) {
            builtin = 1;
            if (cmd->cmd_func != NULL)
                ret = cmd->cmd_func(args);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (! builtin)
        ret = lsh_launch(args);

    return ret;
}

// replaytrim -- limit history
void
replaytrim(void)
{

    for (;  counter > 16;  --counter) {
        // unlink the oldest command
        node *tmp = top;
        top = tmp->next;

        // adjust the tail
        if (tmp == cur)
            cur = top;

        // free its data
        free(tmp->str);
        free(tmp);
    }
}

// replayadd -- add command to the replay buffer
void
replayadd(char *line)
{

    node *m = ALLOCP(m);

    m->str = line;
    m->next = NULL;

    if (cur != NULL)
        cur->next = m;
    else
        top = m;

    cur = m;

    ++counter;

    replaytrim();
}

void
shell_loop(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    char **args = NULL;
// NOTE/BUG: don't use fixed/hardwired buffers
#if 0
    char *allline = malloc(64);
#else
    char *repline = NULL;
#endif
    int state = 1;

    while (state == 1) {
        jobreap();

        printf(">>>$ ");
        fflush(stdout);

        FREE(line);
        line = read_line();

        jobreap();

        repline = strdup(line);

        FREE(args);
        args = split_line(line);

        // space or \t
        if (args[0] == NULL) {
            FREE(repline);
            continue;
        }

        // not replay
        if (strcmp(args[0], "replay") != 0) {
            replayadd(repline);
            state = lsh_execute(args);
            continue;
        }

        // replay command
        else {
            // get index into replay list (origin 1)
            int argidx;
            if (args[1] != NULL)
                argidx = atoi(args[1]);
            else
                argidx = counter + 1;

            // convert to origin 0
            argidx -= 1;

            node *go = top;
            node *prev = NULL;

            // find match in replay list
            for (int i = 0;  go != NULL; i++, go = go->next) {
                if (i == argidx)
                    break;
                prev = go;
            }

            FREE(args);
            FREE(repline);

            if (go == NULL) {
                printf("replay command not found in history -- %d\n",argidx);
                continue;
            }

            // move replay entry to tail of the list
            do {
                // already at the end of list
                if (go == cur)
                    break;

                // unlink entry from middle of list
                if (prev != NULL)
                    prev->next = go->next;
                // unlink entry from front of list
                else
                    top = go->next;

                // make it the newest entry
                cur->next = go;
                go->next = NULL;
                cur = go;
            } while (0);

            repline = strdup(go->str);
            args = split_line(repline);

            state = lsh_execute(args);
        }
    }
}

int
main()
{

#if 1
    setlinebuf(stdout);
#endif

    shell_loop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. 1. Why is fflush necessary? All of my commands are followed with "\n" | 2.-7. This is exactly what I have been searching for. Could you please guide me to some link so that I can understand the concept thoroughly? | 8. I tried to delete the first node if there are over 16 commands. | 10. Is that because the remaining string in the buffer that has not been printed will be copy to the child?

Comment: @高造擎 I updated my answer with some explanation and an updated code example. I had to trim things down a bit to squeeze into the SO 30,000 character limit. So, some things are terser than I would like.